# All shards of elastic search not updating

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES cluster with index "product" which have "department_id" as a field in mapping. Also dynamic updation to mapping is turned off

I am trying to update a specific doc with id 1874184002. This doc doesn't contain any department_id field as of yet. I am trying to update it using query :

```
product/_doc/1874184002/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "department_id": [4655,4654,4652]
  }
}
```

But getting response

```
{
  "_index": "product",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1874184002",
  "_version": 6,
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 51196857,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

I have a total of 24 shards, But i think only one of them is updating.
So when i am querying in Elastic search for updated result.
I dont find any updation.

Can anyone help finding why this is happening

"EDIT" : Updation happened after some time and now i am getting correct result

Maybe due to master slave architecture of shards, Maybe for change to propogate it takes time.

But what i still dont understand why after updation ES showed only 1 shard as updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at firs elastic gives you a response with cached data, which allows faster responses, newer documents take precedence over the ones ingested before. So if you are updating an older document you may have a delay.
[elastic cache docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html)